# Trying installing Lineageos, Reboot my phone but stucked now in the Odinmode

Tags: lineageos, reboot

I am trying to install LineageOs on my Samsung Galaxy J5. Currently i am trying to to reboot my Phone... I writ this in my command:

```
adb devices 
List of devices attached 
1709f084 device emulator-5562 offline

adb reboot bootloader 
error: more than one device/emulator

adb devices
List of devices attached
1709f084 device emulator-5562 offline

adb -s 1709f084 reboot bootloader

fastboot flashing unlock < waiting for any device >
```

Afte writing the command `adb -s 1709f084 reboot bootloader` i t got in the odin mode. After writing the command `fastboot flashing unlock` nothing changed...

What am I doing wrong?

Greetings :)

Comment: samsung devices don't have fastboot mode, therefore no fastboot command will work

Comment: how do i get out of this mode?

Comment: and what kind of command should i use instead? I am Trying to do a  TWRP Recovery...

Comment: read the [manual](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/gts4lvwifi/install#installing-a-custom-recovery-using-odin)

Answer (score 1):

Samsung doesn't have fastboot mode . Use odin to flash your device . If you search online you will find Odin for your computer . Install it . Most likely the Linageos uses custom recovery to flash . If so flash TWRP or any other custom recovery available for your device and flash Linage from there . If you are tring to get out of odin mode . press (power + volume down) to force reboot . if that doesn't work try volume up with power key . Before flasing anything make sure you have activated bootloader unlocking in Devlopers settings :)

Comment: Thanks man :) i got it...I did the hole process until i realiced that lineageos doesnt have a custom rom for the samsung J5 or the samsung galaxy S5 mini. So the hole effort was useless... Do you now a lineageos based custom rom for the J5 or S5 mini? Greeeting :)

Comment: check this https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j5/development/unofficial-lineageos-17-1-beta-galaxy-j5-t4038777 I don't have a j5 so I cann't tell if it works . But if you are looking for a custom rom xda-dev is a good place to start . But before you flash it make sure it's for you device model . It seems samsung has several models named J5